# MCAS white list URLs for embedding

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration

We have enabled MCAS and therefore all URLs are redirected with MCAS, so we need to whitelist those like shown here;

[image]

But is there anyway to do this globally as we can not ask every user to do this every time a new site is created, and do it on all existing sites?

Answer (score 0):

This is a site level setting, I've been unable to find a tenant level setting for this. However, you can set the values programmatically using [Set-PnPSite](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Set-PnPSite.html#-scriptsafedomainname), using the `ScriptSafeDomainName` parameter.

Alternatively, this value can be set using CSOM:

[Site.CustomScriptSafeDomains Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.site.customscriptsafedomains?view=sharepoint-csom)

```
site.CustomScriptSafeDomains.Create(scriptSafeDomainEntity);
context.ExecuteQueryRetry();
```

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Did Callum Crowley's answer helps you?